# A double (perhaps, naive) question on Axiomatic Set Theory

Tags: set-theory

I would like to pose a (perhaps, naive) double question regarding the state of affairs in Axiomatic Set Theory. So, here it is:

"Which Axiomatic Set Theory is the most complete/strong? Zermelo-Fraenkel (with the Axiom of Choice), von-Neumann-Bernays-Goedel, Morse-Kelley or Tarski-Grothendieck?"

Please, also, note the following:

"which is the most **complete** corresponding reference (for introduction and/or further reading)?"

I would like to thank you all, in advance, for your time and help.

Answer (score 9):

In some sense, none of these are complete. They all satisfy the conditions for Gödel's incompleteness theorem, and therefore none of them is complete.

Some remarks:

1. Zermelo–Fraenkel models give rise to models of von Neumann–Gödel–Bernays models (and the class of sets in the latter will be a model of the former). So as far as things go, $\sf ZFC$ and $\sf NBG$ are equivalent in a fairly deep sense.
2. Tarski–Grothendieck set theory is the same as $\sf ZFC$ augmented by "There is a proper class of strongly inaccessible cardinals". Since for an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, $V_{\kappa+1}$ is a model of Morse–Kelley, this theory is much stronger.
3. This means that $\sf\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)\equiv\operatorname{Con}(NBG)<\operatorname{Con}(MK)<\operatorname{Con}(TG)$. So the theory that is "most complete" is $\sf TG$, in that sense.
4. However, none of these theories have anything to say about the Continuum Hypothesis, Martin's Axiom, whether or not $V=L$ holds, and so on and so forth. If we also throw out the axiom of choice from all of these theories, none of them will tell us anything about whether or not $\Bbb R$ can be well-ordered, etc.
5. Lest you think that (4) is a bad thing, do remember that a good foundational theory is a blank canvas on which you get to paint your mathematical universe. It is true, we sometimes want to have a complete background given to us, so that we only need to study its structure. But a foundation of mathematics is meant for us to paint a picture just as well.

Comment: To me, whether you assume CH or MA or V=L (etc.) or not is like the Parallel Postulate: It depends on whether you want to explore Euclidean, hyperbolic, or elliptic geometry. I know very little about NBG but I have read that any sentence in the language of ZFC is a theorem of ZFC iff it is a theorem of NBG.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Indeed.

Comment: @Asaf Karaglia Thank you. So, to put it on a solid basis: a) out of those theories which one would you choose and b) have you any standard (complete) reference in mind?

Comment: @Symmetria Choose for what purpose? Sometimes one is appropriate, sometimes another (just as sometimes Euclidean geometry is appropriate, sometimes hyperbolic geometry is appropriate, etc.).

Comment: @Noah Schweber Yes, your are right, please forgive my ignorance. Well my purpose is to (try to) grasp the needed foundations of mathematics in order to study deeper theoretical physics.

Comment: @Symmetria: For physics? I wouldn't study set theory. Physics happens very very strictly within the confines of the real numbers (here things like $L^1$ are also considered part of the real numbers, for various set theoretic reasons). So third-order arithmetic is probably more than enough, all of which is far far weaker. Unless you are studying something like general category theory and how it applies to physics that takes place in a whole other level that isn't applicable to actual physics (theoretical or otherwise) and you need to learn about proper classes and universes.

Comment: @Symmetria: My point is that all of these theories are exactly the same for your purpose. Pick whichever one is easiest for you to comprehend.

Comment: @Asaf Karaglia. Thank you. Any suggested reference on Axiomatic Set Theory?

Comment: @Symmetria: Jech's "Set Theory", Kunen's "Set Theory" (the new one), Halbeisen's "Combinatorial Set Theory" all present ZF(C). If you want other theories, I'm not sure which ones use that, I think that Engelking's "General Topology" uses MK, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. Also, yes, in the long run, I plan to study general category theory, so (another, separate) reference on proper classes and universes would also be appreciated.

Comment: @Symmetria: Jech talks about classes, I'm pretty sure the others too. There is really not a whole lot to say about them. From the naive point of view (ZF, NBG), classes are "sets that are not really sets", as such they are not elements of any other class. But for the most basic stuff you can do with them most of what you can do with sets. There's really not a lot to say there. TG lets you make your classes sets of a "higher universe", which is where it comes in handy. Oh, you can go to my homepage and find notes from my set theory lectures a couple years back, they might serve as a supplement.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. Thank you very much.